# How to sign SOAP request in Apigee

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, apigee, x509

Does anyone know how to sign a SOAP envelope with X.509 certificate in Apigee? I need to add a new webservice to Apigee Proxy. However this service is secured by SSL. I tried with http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers however is doesn't work form me. I've added certificate to Apigee. And I can see it Apigee

```
myCertKeystore
{
  "certs" : [ "myCert.crt.pem" ],
  "keys" : [ "myCert" ],
  "name" : "myCertKeystore"
}
```

I've also assigned this certificate to my TargetEndpoint

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <SSLInfo>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <ClientAuthEnabled>true</ClientAuthEnabled>
        <KeyStore>myCertKeystore</KeyStore>
        <KeyAlias>myCert</KeyAlias>
    </SSLInfo>
    <URL>https://mywebsercive.url/xxx</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to force Apigee to sign a SOAP request? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-box way to sign soap requests. Need to use javacallouts or scripting to do so. The use of keystore is to validate target backend server SSL. This is entirely a different thing and not related to soap request signing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Darshan, thanks for your answer. It actually makes sense. This is what I thought. I will try with javacallout. Thanks